# After closing the application NSTimer run or not

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

Here Code:

```
timer1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(getLastImageName) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
 runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
[runLoop addTimer:timer1 forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
 [runLoop run];
```

This timer fires an alert when the user presses the wrong option. On click of the alert **OK** button I stop the timer and `runloop`. If the user does not click the **OK** button and instead presses the iPhone home button will the timer be stopped?

Comment: u mean it is keep running while app in background

Comment: @userXXX If the app is not killed, then AFAIK it is - but why don't you try it?

Comment: Dear @user2381789: this question is for ios, osx, document based, window based etc....If you can tell us

Answer (score 4):

Timers do not "run" in the way you're thinking. There is no "count down." A timer simply adds a marker to a run loop to send a certain message at a certain time. Every time the runloop runs, it checks to see if any of the timers have expired (if "now" is later than their fire date). If so, it sends the requested message the same way it does other things like call `drawRect:` or process a touch event or the like. It's more or less a giant `while (true)` loop where one of the things in the loop is "fire expired timers."

So what does all of that mean? It means that timers are only going to fire when the given runloop is being "pumped" (processed). Usually this is the main runloop, and it only gets processed while your application is active. If you become inactive (generally when the user navigates to another app), then the runloop won't process. All the timers that expire while you're inactive will fire when you come back (which is why you usually want to invalidate timers before going into the background). (Non-main runloops are a little more complicated, but pretty rare. They still won't run indefinitely in the background, though, but there are more cases where they fail to run.)

On the other hand, if you're terminated (which can happen without notice while you're in the background), then your runloops are all gone. When you relaunch, your timers won't be instantiated. That's your job if you want it. So you can't rely on your timers ever firing.

Because you've included `repeats:YES`, the timer will be rescheduled for you automatically. Again, this doesn't mean it "counts down" or is "still running" or anything like that. It just means that when it fires, it automatically schedules another timer event. So if the user just sits at the "OK" button for long enough, the timer will fire again (in iOS; things can be a little different on Mac and "modes" matter more there).

Note that there is no reason to call both `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:...` and also `addTimer:...` The "scheduled" part of the method means that the timer has already been added to the runloop.

Answer (score 0):

Is your app running in the background or suspended in the background?

If you haven't added a multitasking mode to your info.plist, your app will be suspended. The timer will be paused until the user resumes your app.

If you have added a multitasking mode and you meet the requirements (e.g. the audio mode, and you're currently playing audio), then your app will still be running, including its timer.

Comment: how to  check app running in multitasking mode?

Comment: app is running in background

Comment: How are you running in the background? Are you using `UIBackgroundModes` in your `Info.plist`, or are you calling `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` somewhere?

Comment: I am using beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler in didEnterBackground method